# Query for exact json keys match in Postgresql (Exacly these keys)

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I'm trying to query after rows that contain a the keys ['kommune', 'fylke', 'år'] in a jsonb columns named data_filters.

As far as i can see postgres only has this operator `?&` which gives me all rows that have all these keys, however i do not want rows that also has (for example) the key 'hobby'. So far I'm using this:

```
select * from main_dataitem 
where array['fylke', 'kommune', 'år'] @> ARRAY(select jsonb_object_keys(data_filters)) 
and ARRAY(select jsonb_object_keys(data_filters)) @> array['fylke', 'kommune', 'år'];
```

However this does not seem like an optimal solution, any one got a better way to query this?

**Just to be clear**, this does not give the desired result because it matches rows that contain the specified keys and plus arbitrary keys (that i did not specify):

```
select * from main_dataitem where data_filters ?& array['fylke', 'kommune', 'år'];
```

Comment: To get the ordered array you would to use `array(select x from jsonb_object_keys(data_filters) as a(x) order by x)` and compare it with the ordered constant array using just `=`.

Comment: I will have to sort both arrays in that case don't i? Also is this faster?

Comment: 1) Yes, both arrays should be sorted (`array[1,2] != array[2,1]`) 2) Just try it. IMO it should be faster but I not the fan of the storing of a structured data as JSON so I have not too much experience in the usage of it.

Answer (score 0):

Probably it should be fastest (except the pure C function):

```
create or replace function jsonb_same_keys(p_json jsonb, p_keys text[])
returns boolean immutable strict language plpythonu as $$
  import json
  j = json.loads(p_json).keys()
  return sorted(j) == sorted(p_keys)
$$;

select jsonb_same_keys('{"1":2,"2":1}'::jsonb, array['2','1']);
╔═════════════════╗
║ jsonb_same_keys ║
╠═════════════════╣
║ t               ║
╚═════════════════╝
```

Of course you should to have the Python installed and the language extension in the PostgreSQL: `create extension plpythonu;`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is still relevant (given this was asked >1 year ago), but I just stumbled on this issue recently.

If you're using jsonb, you can also use the `-` operator. This removes one or more  set of keys from the JSON value. If you're querying only for objects that has the specified keys, then the result of this operation should be an empty JSON (`{}`).

So the query would be:

```
select * from main_dataitem where (data_filters - array['fylke', 'kommune', 'år']) = '{}';
```

Related to @Abelisto's answer (just for completeness), you can also do the JSON key extraction and sorting using the `jsonb_object_keys` / `json_object_keys` function. Something like this:

```
select * from main_dataitem where array(select x from jsonb_object_keys(data_filters) as x order by x) = array['fylke', 'kommune', 'år'];
```

In my own test data set (~330k rows) I've found this to be significantly slower than the first alternative I proposed above though.

Also for the record, I did this in PostgreSQL 10.0.